# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-phoenix

I've been trying to get my get a database connection pool working on my nifi flow. I have it successfully working on NiFi 1.7.0 but when I updated to NiFi 1.9.2 I get the error below.

**Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)**

Connections work on SQuirreL SQL Client and NiFi-1.7.0 which is strange. The error message is very vague I have not been able to find any solution for this.

I am using the phoenix queryserver with the phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-thin-client.jar.

DBCP processor settings are all default, besides:

- class name: org.apache.phoenix.queryserver.client.Driver
- url: jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=http://localhost:8765;serialization=PROTOBUF

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:474)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:222)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2385)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2110)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:470)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.unsupported(Helper.java:72)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.isValid(AvaticaConnection.java:376)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:874)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:270)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:389)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2398)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2381)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The message is coming from phoenix. So, smth wrong with url format

Answer (score 1):

Setting a validation query that returns at least one row in the DBCP controller service fixed it.

Comment: In 1.8.0 we switched from DBCP to DBCP2, sounds like it tries to validate the connection ahead of time where it did not used to. Glad you got it to work, I highly recommend always setting a Validation Query. It is not required because it is database specific.